# Unable to get data on joining Multiple Eloquent Relationships

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, eloquent-relationship

i wanted to display `id`,`FileName` & `FilePath` from `Files` table and `id` & `name` from `User` table along with the `course` table columns - `id`,`courseDisplayName` & `aboutCourse`. But it is returning `null` from both `files` & `user` relations.How can i fix this?

```
$course=Course::with(['files:id,FileName,FilePath','user:id,name'])
->select('id','courseDisplayName','aboutCourse')
->where('userId',$request->tutorId)
->get();
```

**Course Model**

```
  public function files()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Files::class, 'fileId', 'id');
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'userId', 'id');
    }
```

This gives an output as below:

```
[
    {
        "id": 20,
        "courseDisplayName": "asasasb",
        "aboutCourse": null,
        "files": null,
        "user": null
    },
    {
        "id": 14,
        "courseDisplayName": "yuu",
        "aboutCourse": "kljkl",
        "files": null,
        "user": null
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to select the foreign keys `fileId` and `userId` too in order to use the relationship of `files` and `user` so the query will be like

```
$course=Course::with(['files:id,FileName,FilePath','user:id,name'])
->select('id','courseDisplayName','aboutCourse', 'userId', 'fileId')
->where('userId',$request->tutorId)
->get();
```